# AspNet Dotnet Core API call Get with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

As in the description I have set up a website where are exposed some API:

Startup.cs is setup as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default", 
      pattern: "{controller}/{id}");
  });
}
```

The only controller (named `Controller`) has the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
  return new string[] { "Hello", "World" };
}

[HttpGet("{incomingString}")]
public string GetString(string incomingString)
{
    return incomingString;
}
```

When I launch the project the page `http://localhost:60026/Controller` is opened and `Get()` is called.
To trigger `GetString` I have to add `/<some string>` to the url, which is not how it is supposed to be.

I'm trying to call `GetString` from a client using `HttpClint.GetAsync()` but i have not succeded to call it or pass anything to it.

Comment: "which is not how it is supposed to be."...how do you want it to be then exactly? There are many ways it could be configured, potentially. Be specific about your requirement

Comment: You are right. I figured it out that I didn't understand what I was doing. I just replaced `[HttpGet("{incomingString}")]` with `[HttpGet] [Route("GetString")]` and added `[FromQuery]` before method parameter.